# Python - Scipy : ode module : issue enabling the step option of the solver

Tags: python, scipy, numerical-methods, ode

I wanted to store the different integration steps taken by the solver itself when I call it :

```
solver1.integrate(t_end)
```

So I did a while loop and enabled the step option setting its value to `True`:

```
while solver1.successful() and solver1.t < t0+dt:
    solver1.integrate(t_end,step=True)
    time.append(solver1.t)
```

Then I plot `y`, the result  of integration and here comes my issue. I have instabilities which appear in a located area :

[image: y enabling the step option of the solver]

I thought it was because of the loop or something like that so I checked the result removing the `step` :

```
while solver1.successful() and solver1.t < t0+dt:
    solver1.integrate(t_end)
```

And surprise ... I have the correct result :

[image: y disabling the step option of the solver]

It's a quite weird situation ... I'd be grateful if someone of your guys could help me with this issue.

EDIT :

To set the solver I do :

```
solver1 = ode(y_dot,jac).set_integrator('vode',with_jacobian=True)
solver1.set_initial_value(x0,t0)
```

And I store the result using `.append()`

Comment: Can you show some more of your code, how you set up the solver and store the result for plotting?

Comment: Of course, I've just edited my question.

Comment: You still haven't shown how you are actually storing the current ODE state which you are plotting, presuming that the plots show one of the ODE state variables.

Answer (score 2):

When you set `step=True` you are indirectly giving the `vode._integrator.runner` (a Fortran subroutine) an instruction to use `itask=2`, and the default is `itask=1`. You can get more details about this `runner` doing:

```
r._integrator.runner?
```

In SciPy 0.12.0 documentation you will not find an explanation about what is going on for the different `itask=1` or `itask=2`, [but you can find it here](http://www.radford.edu/~thompson/vodef90web/Documentation/Original_Prologue.txt):

```
ITASK  = An index specifying the task to be performed.
!          Input only. ITASK has the following values and meanings.
!          1  means normal computation of output values of y(t) at
!             t = TOUT(by overshooting and interpolating).
!          2  means take one step only and return.
!          3  means stop at the first internal mesh point at or
!             beyond t = TOUT and return.
!          4  means normal computation of output values of y(t) at
!             t = TOUT but without overshooting t = TCRIT.
!             TCRIT must be input as RUSER(1). TCRIT may be equal to
!             or beyond TOUT, but not behind it in the direction of
!             integration. This option is useful if the problem
!             has a singularity at or beyond t = TCRIT.
!          5  means take one step, without passing TCRIT, and return.
!             TCRIT must be input as RUSER(1).
```